# Find pattern in binary file/ Find match in binary file (C)

Tags: c

I don't know why this code isn't working.

```
while (TRUE)
{
    do
    {
        fread(buffer1, BUFFER_LEN - 1, 1, pFile);
        fread(buffer2, BUFFER_LEN - 1, 1, pVirus);
        if (feof(pVirus))
        {
            printf("MATCH!\n");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    } while (strcmp(buffer1, buffer2) == 0);

    if (buffer1 != buffer2)
    {
        rewind(pVirus);
    }

    if (feof(pFile) || flag == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
}

fclose(pFile);
fclose(pVirus);
```

The code finding match in small file in bigger file the code isn't working.

Comment: comparing memory using `strcmp` will fail if there are zeroes in it.

Comment: How should i compare?

Comment: Google or man memcmp

Comment: can we compare buffer1 and buffer2 with != operator ?

Comment: always check the returned value from every call to `fread()`  and do not call `feof()` unless the returned value from`fread()` was 0

Comment: regarding: `if (buffer1 != buffer2)`  This will NEVER be true as it is comparing two memory addresses.  Suggest: `if( memcmp( buffer1, buffer2,

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired function
2. cannot say it cleanly compiles as the OPs posted code is not complete
3. will not seg fault

and now the proposed code:

```
    rewind( pFile );
    do
    {
        size_t buf1Count = fread(buffer1, 1, BUFFER_LEN, pFile);
        if( !buf1Count )
        {
            if( feof( pFile ) )
            { // reached end of pFile
                ???
                break;
            }

            else
            { // error event
                perror( "fread of pFile failed" );
                fclose( pFile );
                fclose( pVirus );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }

        rewind( pVirus );
        do
        {
            size_t buf2Count = fread(buffer2, 1, BUFFER_LEN, pVirus);

            if( !buf2Count )
            {
                if( feof( pVirus ) )
                { // reached end of pVirus
                    printf( "NO MATCH\n" );
                    break;
                }

                else
                { // error event
                    perror( "fread of pVirus failed" );
                    fclose( pFile );
                    fclose( pVirus );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
            }

            if( memcmp(buffer1, buffer2, buf1Count) == 0)
            {
                printf( "MATCH\n" );
                break;
            }
        } while(1);
    } while (1);

    fclose(pFile);
    fclose(pVirus);
```